# is there anyway to force a link to open up in IE, even if not the default browser

Tags: html, browser

we have a website with links to a sharepoint.  These features in sharepoint only work in IE so i dont want to open up firefox or chrome if that is the default browser.  Is there anyway to have a

```
 <a href= "">My Link</a>
```

force open up in internet explorer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javascript to inject the link in your HTML code if the client is IE, and maybe show a warning message if the browser isn't IE. Anyway you can't tell any browser to open a link using *another* browser.

Answer (score 0):

No, definitely not.

For Firefox users, the best thing that comes to mind is to have them install the [IE tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/10909/). It allows the opening of pages inside Firefox but using the IE engine - but also requires user action.

Answer (score 0):

If this is run in a windows environment, you could use a PHP script to open Internet Explorer through PHPs support for COM objects.

If you are interested I can provide the script to do this.